# What is WriteConcern in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Please explain me what is write concern in mongodb in the easiest way possible and also mention work of w: j: and wtimeout:

Comment: Did you read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/index.html

Comment: Yes, I understood a little bit  but I want to know at which type of situation we are gonna use it